# Finitely generated group and quadratic isoperimetric functions.

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

It is well known that a finitely generated group with 
simply connected cones has isoperimetric functions. 
Papasoglu in the paper "On the Asymptotic cone of groups satisfying a quadratic isoperimetric inequality" shows that every group satisfying a quadratic isoperimetric inequality is simply connected. 
However as far as I understood the proof, the argument needs a finite presentation of the groups, indeed it uses a triangular presentation (page 796) that can be constructed only from a finite presentation.

Here is my question: Can the result be concluded for finitely generated groups with quadratic isoperimetric functions? And if yes why?

Thanks.

Comment: The whole concept of isoperimetric functions in groups only makes sense for groups with a finite presentation.

Comment: Hi Derek, could you be a bit more precise please ? I mean why it does not make sense if the presentation is decidable ?

Comment: I guess it makes sense for a specific presentation, but you were talking about groups with quadratic isoperimetric functions, without reference to presentations. This is justified by the fact that the property in question is independent of the choice of finite presentation. So results about isoperimetric functions of groups tacitly assume that the groups are finitely presented.

Comment: the natural convention is that the isoperimetric function of an infinitely presented f.g. group is the $\infty$ function. To be finitely presented means that every large enough loop splits into loops of smaller size, and an (finitely valued) isoperimetric function is a kinda quantitative version of this.

Answer (score 2):

If a group is not finitely presented, it always has a non-simply-connected asymptotic cone.  I won't put a full proof here, but the strategy is to pick a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of naturals corresponding to lengths of irreducible relations (here "irreducible" just means it can't be derived from shorter relations), and show the cycles in the Cayley graph corresponding to these relations converge to a non-trivial loop in any cone constructed from an ultrafilter containing $\{a_n\}$.

Thus, the statement is vacuously false for non finitely-presented groups, regardless of how you deal with the issues around isoperimetric functions on such groups.

Comment: A detailed proof (different from what you have sketched) of this result (due to Gromov) can be found in: C. Druţu, Quasi-isometry invariants and asymptotic cones. International Conference on Geometric and Combinatorial Methods in Group Theory and Semigroup Theory (Lincoln, NE, 2000). Internat. J. Algebra Comput. 12 (2002), no. 1-2, 99–135.